# I want to keep sync the session with user sign information in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET MVC 4.7.2. I am getting some users' information from Azure AD and store that in session so I do not have to call back again until session is live.

But the problem is when the user close the window or signs out, the session also ends, however user can still sign in without authentication process.

So I want to sync save the user information in the same cache or cookie so both expires at the same time. I thought of using the `httpContext` but read it might create some problem. Currently I am using a session but it is not a good choice. I found some other solution but they are very old.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is no sensitive data cookie seems to be the best choice. You can also use the [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) option but it will be shared by all users.